# I "reverted a commit" and lost days of progress. How do I get my progress back?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, github-desktop

In Github Desktop I tried to commit and sync progress (like the fool I am, the last time I sent a commit was 4 days ago). I got an error message saying something like the push didn't succeed because one of the files exceeded 100MB (I am looking into adding this file to .gitignore). I checked my github account online to see if any of the files got pushed and none did. I checked on Github Desktop and couldn't see any of the files. I thought to myself this isn't good because if it's not detecting these changes anymore how am I supposed to attempt to commit them again? In a panic, I seen the following "Revert this commit" button thinking my changes would show up in Github Desktop again:

[image]

I pressed Revert this Commit and nothing noticeable happened. I think I then pressed Revert this Commit again on something (bad habit..). After more panic, I thought I would just make a small change to one of my files to see if the change shows up in Github Desktop. It did. So I committed and synced this change. I checked my github account online and I could see it was pushed successfully. This is where I realize I really messed up. I go back to Android Studio and I now realize that days of progress (a bunch of missing files) are gone (because being the idiot I am I waited days to back up). At this point I think I just lost the progress I made. I am wondering if there is anyway I can get it back? Upon doing a bit of research I attempted the git reflog command and I notice some words like revert and reset. I am wondering if this is enough to work with to get my progress back?

[image]

I am scared to attempt anything else without advice because as proven I like to wreck things =(

Comment: You can just `git checkout <id>` where <id> is the SHA id in the first column of your reflog output. `git checkout 284XXX` (the id in the HEAD@{4} line) should bring you back to the point before the resets and the revert. EDIT: Also: Relax. As long as your changes were commited at any time, you most probably *will* get them back.

Comment: What does "revert this commit" mean to GitHub desktop?  In the context of pure Git, a revert just means that you made a _new_ commit on top of your branch which functionally undoes some stuff.  In the context of GitHub desktop, it might mean doing a reset of some sort.  In any case, the reflog should have every commit, deleted or not, so you can reset your branch to some earlier point, if that would work for you.

Comment: Note: for removing large files, BFG is easier than filter-branch: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/